# Flutter pageView setOffscreenPageLimit alternative

Tags: flutter

Android viewPager has a `setOffscreenPageLimit` method to determine the number of invisible pages that should be pre-create and retained. I wonder if there is an alternative solution for Flutter pageView widget?